# Laravel 5.2.* Laravel/socialite catch when facebook deny access

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm using Laravel 5.2.* and laravel/socialite 2.0.14 and everything is fine when when trying login to facebook and in Facebook click "Okay".

But if I try to login with Facebook for the very first time and if I Click "Cancel" on Facebook to deny access, it redirect to the callback URI and triggers and error.

[image]

[image]

Here is my Controller code,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Socialite;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function facebook()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

     public function facebookCallback()
     {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

        // $user->token;

        dd($user);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to catch the error or solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`try catch`](https://laravel.io/forum/05-21-2015-try-catch-not-working) to catch exceptions. Like this:

```
try {
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    do something.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `try catch` method for deny catch

```
try {

    if (!$request->has('code') || $request->has('denied')) {
       return redirect('/');       // redirect url
    }

    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
}
catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    return redirect()->to('/');   // redirect url
}
```